# ionic2 http post not sending parameters

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to use http post with ionic 2 but I can't send parameters to the server

```
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public shareServices: ShareServices, public http: Http) {
    this.data = {};
    this.data.email = '';
    this.data.password = '';    
}

login()
{
    let url = 'http://localhost/wp/ap/user/generate_auth_cookie/?insecure=cool';

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = {
        email : this.data.username,
        password : this.data.password,
    }

    this.http.post(url,JSON.stringify(body), options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
    data  => {
        this.resp = data.json();
        console.log('RESP', this.resp);
    },
    err => {
        this.resp = err.json();
        console.log('ERROR', this.resp);
    }
  );
 }
```

I'm using WordPress User Api Plugin

> https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/

Comment: any errors you have?

Comment: No, there is no errors found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you  catch any error? maybe you can try like this:

```
let body = "username="+username+"&password="+password;


            let headers = new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            });
            let options = new RequestOptions({
                headers: headers,
                body: body
            });

            this.http.post(url, body, options)
          .subscribe(
```

Comment: thank you , it's working for me, but how can i get response as a JSON

Comment: this.http.post(url, body, options)
    .subscribe(
   response => {
    
    var result  = response.json();//result is json object
   },
   error => {
    console.log('error'); 
   }
    );